# React-hooks/exhaustive-deps | Erro em uma função assync ao pegar dados de uma API

Tags: php, mysql, json, react

Olá, estou tendo um erro em React.Js que não compreendo na tentativa de consumir dados de uma API que eu mesmo criei.
criei um loop para que eu conseguisse pegar as informações do json e printasse me meu site.

Abaixo o código seguido do erro:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Produtos = () => {
    const [produtos, setProdutos] = useState([]);

    useEffect(async() => {
        const result = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/React3/fse/src/php/produtosapi.php");
        setProdutos(await result.json());
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    {   
                        produtos.map(value => {
                            return (
                                
                                <div className="col-lg-3">
                                    <div key={value.id}>
                                        <img src= {value.imagem} alt="a" width="120" height="120" />
                                        <h5>{value.descricao}</h5>
                                        <h5>R$:{value.preco}</h5>
                                        <br /> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })     
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Produtos;
```

erro: "effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. put the async function inside:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fale cara, então, você não pode está usando o `async` dentro do `useEffect` você deve chamar uma função para executar dentro dele e em seguida chama-la, fiz um exemplo de como pode está resolvendo seu problema:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Produtos = () => {
    const [produtos, setProdutos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getProducts(){
      await fetch("http://localhost:8080/React3/fse/src/php/produtosapi.php")
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setProdutos([data]);
        });
    }
        
     getProducts();
        
    }, [produtos]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    {   
                        produtos.map(value => {
                            return (
                                
                                <div className="col-lg-3">
                                    <div key={value.id}>
                                        <img src= {value.imagem} alt="a" width="120" height="120" />
                                        <h5>{value.descricao}</h5>
                                        <h5>R$:{value.preco}</h5>
                                        <br /> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })     
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Produtos;
```

Comment: Por que você colocou `produtos` como dependência do `useEffect`? E por que está usando `.then` com `async` e `await`?

Comment: Achei que ficaria melhor o exemplo, você pode está combinando os dois sem problemas, toda função assíncrona retorna promises. Em relação aos produtos, quando colocado como dependência, o component é renderizado toda vez que tiver uma atualização no state de produtos. @RafaelTavares

Comment: Se você atualiza o estado dentro do `useEffect`, e o estado é uma dependência, estará fazendo um loop infinito. Além disso, você nem precisa de `async` e `await` usando o `then` do modo como está no código

Comment: Beleza cara, mas fiz o teste não deu loop infinito, tenta também, em relacão ao `then` eu sei que não precisa, mas como disse achei que ficaria melhor pra exemplificar, só isso. abraços @RafaelTavares

Comment: Está certo, não entrará num loop infinito se a API retornar o mesmo valor, mas estará fazendo um request a mais.